# How to define the "source.find" part of BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I need to scrape a list of restaurant links from a food delivery website to afterwards scrape their menus. This is the site i wanna scrape: https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/monserrat/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1

Inspecting the HTML:

```
<a href="https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el- 
noble-galerias-pacifico-menu" title="El Noble Galerías Pacífico" 
class="arrivalName">El Noble Galerías Pacífico</a>
```

The parts I'm interested in are:

URL = https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-galerias-pacifico-menu

NAME = El Noble Galerías Pacífico

Saved in different lists and then later create a .CSV

Site has several pages but I'll get to that issue later hahah. This is my code:

```
urls = []

source = BeautifulSoup(page_soup, "html.parser")
table = source.find('h3', attrs={'a': 'arrivalName'})
for a in table.find_all("a", href=True):
    print(a)
    urls.append(a)
```

I'm getting this error: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

Comment: can you provide a [minimal working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and the full traceback so we can help you more efficiently?

Comment: Hi Zaccharie, thanks very much for your comment. I already got a solution from QHarr. But thanks!

Comment: Sure, next time don't forget to add it though as it will help you solve the problem on your own or help others help you faster and better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use class name to target the restaurant links then extract the href for the link and the .text for the name. I generate a df as tidier but you can slice out name column and link.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests
import pandas as pd
import math

url = 'https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/monserrat/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1'
results = []
with requests.Session() as s:
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
    restuarants = [(item.text, item['href']) for item in soup.select('.arrivalName')]
    results.append(restuarants)
    num_per_page = 50
    total = int(soup.select_one('.addressTitle i').text)
    num_pages = math.ceil(total/num_per_page)
    if num_pages > 1:
        for page in range(2, num_pages + 1):
            r = s.get('https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/monserrat/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page=1'.format(page))     
            soup = bs(r.content, 'lxml')
            restuarants = [(item.text, item['href']) for item in soup.select('.arrivalName')]
            results.append(restuarants)

final =  [item for sublist in results for item in sublist]
df = pd.DataFrame(final, columns = ['name', 'link'])
df.to_csv(r"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Data.csv", sep=',', encoding='utf-8-sig',index = False )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to iterate over the pages, pull out the data and dump to CSV without pandas:

```
import csv
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base = "https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/monserrat/empanadas-delivery?bt=RESTAURANT&page="
restaurants = [["name", "url"]]
page = 1

while True:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(base + str(page)).text, "html.parser")
    elements = soup.find_all("a", href=True, attrs={"class": "arrivalName"})
    page += 1

    if not elements: break

    for elem in elements:
        restaurants.append([elem.text, elem["href"]])

with open("restaurants.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(restaurants)
```

Output CSV contents:

```
name,url
CaracasBread,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/caracasbread-menu
El Noble Galerías Pacífico,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-galerias-pacifico-menu
El Hornero de San Telmo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-hornero-de-san-telmo-menu
Kiosco De Empanadas - Microcentro,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/kiosco-de-empanadas-microcentro-menu
Pata Pizza Saavedra,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pata-pizza-saavedra-menu
Aji Argentina,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/aji-argentina-menu
El Banco Rojo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-banco-rojo-menu
Pizzería La Bomba,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-la-bomba-menu
Lopecito,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/lopecito-menu
Tía Luisa,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/tia-luisa-menu
El Codo de Oro,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-codo-de-oro-menu
Pizzeria Genova Av. Corrientes,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-genova-av-corrientes-menu
Arepas Tricolor,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/arepas-tricolor-menu
Parados Urban Food,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/parados-urban-food-menu
Angélica,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/angelica-menu
Fratello's San Cristóbal,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/fratellos-san-cristobal-menu
Cartagena Bar,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cartagena-bar-menu
Mr Sandwich - San Telmo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/mr-sandwich-san-telmo-menu
Capataz,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/capataz-menu
Pizza Alla Pala Entre Rios,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizza-alla-pala-entre-rios-menu
Sushi Boom,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/sushi-boom-menu
Pizzería Don Cruz,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-don-cruz-menu
Pizzería Grandi,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-grandi-menu
Nápoles,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/napoles-menu
Pizza Yerman Rodríguez Peña,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizza-yerman-rodriguez-pena-menu
La Cacerola de Monserrat,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-cacerola-de-monserrat-menu
El SanguCHE,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-sanguche-menu
Alameda Restaurante,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/alameda-restaurante-menu
i Fresh Resto,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/i-fresh-resto-menu
De Diez,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/de-diez-menu
I Fresh Deli,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/i-fresh-deli-menu
Amelia's Balvanera,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/amelias-balvanera-menu
Defensa Bar Restaurant,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/defensa-bar-restaurant-menu
Defensa II Pizzería bar restaurante,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/defensa-ii-pizzeria-bar-restaurante-menu
Hachi's Burger 67,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/hachi-s-burger-67-menu
Sandwich Factory,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/sandwich-factory-menu
Victoria - Bar Notable,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/victoria-bar-notable-menu
La Rosa de Guadalupe Heladería,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-rosa-de-guadalupe-heladeria-menu
El Rincón de las Hamburguesas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-rincon-de-las-hamburguesas-menu
La Farola de Abasto,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-farola-abasto-menu
ATR 1 Night! Drinks and Fast Food,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/atr-1-night-drinks-and-fast-food-menu
La Farola de Congreso,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-farola-de-congreso-menu
Natacha,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/natacha-menu
Empanadas de 10 Balvanera,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/empanadas-de-10-balvanera-menu
Mostachole Empanadas Gourmet,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/mostachole-empanadas-gourmet-menu
El Noble Barracas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-barracas-menu
El Noble San Cristóbal,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-noble-san-cristobal-menu
Morita Montserrat,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/morita-montserrat-menu
Kiosco de Empanadas Congreso,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/kiosco-de-empanadas-congreso-menu
Homero Pizzas Almagro,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/homero-pizzas-almagro-menu
Xiang Xing,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/xiang-xing-menu
Ketchup Flores,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/ketchup-flores-menu
Keni's,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/keni-s-menu
Keni's,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/keni-s-menu
Lo de Ale,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/lo-de-ale-menu
Lo de Ale,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/lo-de-ale-menu
Pedro Telmo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pedro-telmo-menu
Pedro Telmo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pedro-telmo-menu
Villegas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/villegas-menu
Villegas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/villegas-menu
Fox Palermo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/fox-palermo-menu
Urban Food Raúl Scalabrini Ortíz,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/urban-food-ra%C3%BAl-scalabrini-ort%C3%ADz-menu
Papelon,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/papelon-menu
Empanadas Express - Suipacha,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/empanadas-express-suipacha-menu
Empanadas Gourmet Microcentro,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/empanadas-gourmet-microcentro-menu
Empanadas Gourmet Microcentro,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/empanadas-gourmet-microcentro-menu
Empanairo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/empanairo-menu
Solo Super Hamburguesas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/solo-super-hamburguesas-menu
Empanadas Factory,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/empanadas-factory-menu
Bocanada,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/bocanada-menu
D'Mosqueras,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/d-mosqueras-menu
Caro Fratello Pizzería,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/caro-fratello-pizzeria-menu
Señora Empanada,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/senora-empanada-menu
Señora Empanada,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/senora-empanada-menu
El Conde,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-conde-pizza-empanadas-menu
El Conde,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-conde-pizza-empanadas-menu
El Simoqueño,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-simoqueno-menu
El Simoqueño,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-simoqueno-menu
El Maestro Pizzas y Empanadas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-maestro-pizzas-y-empanadas-menu
El Maestro Pizzas y Empanadas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-maestro-pizzas-y-empanadas-menu
La Napolitana,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-napolitana-menu
La Napolitana,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-napolitana-menu
La Bella Vita,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-bella-vita-menu
Pizzería La Bomba,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-la-bomba-menu
Pizzería La Bomba,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-la-bomba-menu
Don Armando San Telmo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/don-armando-san-telmo-menu
Sei Tu Entre Ríos,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/sei-tu-entre-rios-menu
La Nueva Salomé,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-nueva-salome-menu
Kalinka Bistró,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/kalinka-bistro-menu
La Continental Avenida,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-continental-avenida-menu
La Continental Avenida,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-continental-avenida-menu
La Continental Entre Ríos 415,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-continental-entre-rios-415-menu
La Continental Entre Ríos 415,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-continental-entre-rios-415-menu
Los 36 Billares,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/los-36-billares-menu
Los 36 Billares,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/los-36-billares-menu
Hausbrot Recoleta,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/hausbrot-recoleta-menu
Hausbrot Santa Fe,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/hausbrot-santa-fe-menu
"Sergio, Casa de Comidas",https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/sergio-casa-de-comidas-menu
Chelvíe,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/chelvie-menu
Chelvíe,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/chelvie-menu
Señora Empanada,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/senora-empanada-menu
La Bella Vita,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-bella-vita-menu
La Continental Entre Ríos 415,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-continental-entre-rios-415-menu
El Conde,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-conde-pizza-empanadas-menu
La Nueva Salomé,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-nueva-salome-menu
Kalinka Bistró,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/kalinka-bistro-menu
El Simoqueño,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-simoqueno-menu
El Maestro Pizzas y Empanadas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/el-maestro-pizzas-y-empanadas-menu
24k,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/24k-menu
Hausbrot Recoleta,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/hausbrot-recoleta-menu
La Continental Avenida,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-continental-avenida-menu
La Napolitana,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-napolitana-menu
Chelvíe,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/chelvie-menu
"Sergio, Casa de Comidas",https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/sergio-casa-de-comidas-menu
Solera Mesón,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/solera-meson-menu
Los 36 Billares,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/los-36-billares-menu
Baguette & Co.,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/baguette-co-menu
Hausbrot Santa Fe,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/hausbrot-santa-fe-menu
Parrilla El Formoseño,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/parrilla-el-formoseno-menu
Tío Felipe,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/tio-felipe-menu
Arbol De Café,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/arbol-de-caf%C3%A9-menu
Don Valentin,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/don-valentin-menu
Bargley,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/bargley-menu
Colombian Coffe - Store,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/colombian-coffe-store-menu
Pizzeria la Torre de Retiro,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pizzeria-la-torre-de-retiro-menu
Cristobalino,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cristobalino-menu
Manolo Bufette Bar,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/manolo-bufette-bar-menu
Il Fratello Ristorante,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/ilfratello-ristorante-menu
Tagliata,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/tagliata-menu
Javi's Parrilla - Restaurant,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/javi-s-parrilla-restaurant-menu
Bar El Crack,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/bar-el-crack-menu
Solera,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/solera-menu
Malva Café Resto Bar,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/malva-cafe-resto-bar-menu
Sabri - Comidas Ricas,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/sabri-comidas-ricas-menu
Hendriks,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/hendriks-menu
D'oro Italian Bar,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/d-oro-italian-bar-menu
Nueva Era - Parrilla Restaurant,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/nueva-era-parrilla-restaurant-menu
Plan B,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/plan-b-menu
Los Amigos San Telmo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/los-amigos-san-telmo-menu
Cannarelli Pescados & Mariscos,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/cannarelli-pescados-mariscos-menu
Vos y Yo,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/vos-y-yo-menu
Nico's Bar Porteño,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/nico-s-bar-porteno-menu
Lo Nuestro café y resto,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/lo-nuestro-cafe-y-resto-menu
Buen Provecho,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/buen-provecho-menu
Paulis Fast Good - Café,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/paulis-fast-good-cafe-menu
La Academia,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-academia-menu
Food & Coffee,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/food-%26-coffee-menu
Junin Chioco,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/junin-chioco-menu
Babilonia Talcahuano,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/babilonia-talcahuano-menu
Pola,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/pola-menu
La Perla Recoleta,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/la-perla-recoleta-menu
Rotisería Vegetariana La Verde,https://www.pedidosya.com.ar/restaurantes/buenos-aires/rotiseria-vegetariana-la-verde-menu
```

Comment: Thanks mate! You are gold!